# Multiprocessor Atomic Operations

Tags: multiprocessing, cpu, atomic, cpu-architecture

How do multi-processor atomic operations work? Suppose two Processors signal they want to access the same memory location at the same time - who gets control? Is it decided by internal circuitry?

Comment: For x86, see [Can num++ be atomic for 'int num'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39393850).  For other ISAs, some use LL/SC (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load-link/store-conditional).  For write-only atomic operations (not RMW), see [Can multiple CPUs simultaneously write to the same RAM location?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/516940) - yes, whichever core gets exclusive ownership of the cache line commits its store first.

Comment: So how does one verify they have attained control of a memory location if there isn't a set order for claiming access? Imagine 4 CPU all attempting to claim access to the same location at the same time - how does a core verify it has attained control?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MESI_protocol - only one core will get a reply to its Read For Ownership granting it exclusive ownership, or acknowledgements from other cores that they've invalidated their copies.  Intel engineers have said Intel CPUs have a "contention manager" that decides which cores should get access next if many are contending for access.

Comment: I forget if [What Every Programmer Should Know About Memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8126311) mentions multi-core says anything about MESI and multiple cores.  It's fairly old, when multi-core was very new (but still highly relevant).

Comment: And BTW, in my first comment, I linked [Can multiple CPUs simultaneously write to the same RAM location?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/516940) without really reading the answers.  I retract my recommendation to see that Q&A.  The top answer has a couple mistakes and doesn't say anything really specific.

Comment: See [What happens when different CPU cores write to the same RAM address without synchronization?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48817022) for pure stores, and atomic ops on x86-style CPUs (single-instruction RMW, not LL/SC)